# Understanding output of 'predict' in R

Tags: r, prediction

I'm trying to understand the output from predict(), as well as understand whether this approach is appropriate for the problem I'm trying to solve. The prediction intervals don't make sense to me, but when I plot this on a scatterplot it looks like a good model:

[image]

I created a simple linear regression model of deal size ($) with a company's sales volume as a predictor variable. The data is faked, with deal size being a multiple of sales volume plus or minus some noise:

```
    Call:
lm(formula = deal_size ~ sales_volume, data = accounts)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-19123502  -3794671  -3426616   4838578  17328948 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.709e+06  1.727e+05   21.48   <2e-16 ***
sales_volume 1.898e-01  2.210e-03   85.88   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6452000 on 1586 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.823, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8229 
F-statistic:  7376 on 1 and 1586 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The predictions were generated thusly:

```
d = data.frame(accounts, predict(fit, interval="prediction"))
```

When I plot sales_volume vs. deal_size on a scatterplot, and overlay the regression line with the prediction interval, it looks good, except for a few intervals that span negative values where sales is at or near zero.

I understand fit is the predicted value, but what are lwr and upr? Do they define the intervals in absolute terms (y coordinates)? The intervals seem to be extremely wide, wider than would make sense if my model was a good fit:

```
sales_volume    deal_size    fit            lwr          upr
0               0            3709276.494    -8950776.04  16369329.03
0               8586337.22   3709276.494    -8950776.04  16369329.03      
110000          549458.6512  3730150.811    -8929897.298 16390198.92
```

Comment: maybe take a look at `?predict.lm`

Comment: Post complete code.With only output we have no way of helping identifying the problem.

Comment: I've put together a short document that demonstrates working of both intervals. http://rpubs.com/RomanL/7024

Comment: what function do I use to plot such diagram in R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `predict` with an `lm` model, you can specify an `interval`. You have three choices: `none` will not return intervals, `confidence` and `prediction`. Both of those will return different values. The first column will be as you said the predicted values (column `fit`). You then have two other columns : `lwr` and `upper` which are the lower and upper levels of the confidence intervals.

What is the difference between `confidence` and `prediction` ?

`confidence` is a (by default 95%, use `level` if you wish to change that) confidence interval of the mean of the predicted value. It is the green interval on your plot. Whereas `prediction` is a (also 95%) confidence interval of all your values, meaning that should you repeat your experience/survey/... a huge number of times, you can expect that 95% of your values will fall in the yellow interval, thus making it a lot wider than the green one as the green one only evaluates the mean.

And as you an see on your plot, almost all values are in the yellow interval. R doesn't know that your values can  only be positive so it explains why the yellow interval "begins" under 0.

Also, when you say "The intervals seem to be extremely wide, wider than would make sense if my model was a good fit", you can see in your plot that the interval is not that big, considering that you can expect 95% of the values to be in it, and you can clearly see a trend in your data. And your model is clearly a good fit as the adjusted R squared and the global p-value tells you.

Answer (score 4):

Just a slight rephrasing of @etienne above, which is very good and accurate.

Confidence interval is the (1-alpha; eg 95%) interval for the mean prediction (or group response). IE if you have 10 new companies with sales volume of `2e+08` the `predict(..., interval= "confidence")` interval will give you the long-run average interval for your group mean.

With Var(\hat y|X= x*) = \sigma^2 (1/n + (x*-\bar x)^2 / SXX)

The prediction interval is the (1-alpha; eg 95%) interval for an individual response -- `predict(..., interval= "predict")`. IE for a single new company with sales volume of `2e+08`...

With Var(\hat y|X= x*) = \sigma^2 (1 + 1/n + (x*-\bar x)^2 / SXX)

(Sorry that LaTeX isn't supported)